# Dota 2 Minimap in DotA

Tags: dota-2, dota

I know there are many mods available to make DotA UI similar to Dota 2. However, I'm in need of a very simple change.

I just need the minimap of Dota 2 to be imported into DotA. I'm not interested in any other things like icons, sounds, hero models, terrain etc.

I've opened a similar thread at [**PlayDota**](http://www.playdota.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1212056) (of course you would need an account to view the thread. Apologies to those who don't have it) I followed the procedure mentioned there but without any success. After trying numerous times I gave up and decided to seek a solution here.

Are there any ready made mods available which suit my requirement? I'm also ready to carry out instructions give to me here (If any)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok! I figured it out myself. For those having a similar problem, here is what I did

### Stage 1

- Downloaded MPQMaster
- Opened DotA 6.77 map with [**MPQMaster**](http://www.hiveworkshop.com/forums/tools-560/mpq-master-v1-2-0-a-62935/)
- Deleted War3mapMap.blp file
- Imported the Dota 2 War3mapMap.blp file
- Hit Operations->Compact(Flush)

### Stage 2

- Downloaded [**WinMPQ**](http://www.hiveworkshop.com/forums/tools-560/winmpq-v1-64-a-62969/)
- Opened the newly modified DotA 6.77 map
- Hit Compact->Yes->Yes

That's it. The second stage is to reduce the filesize and bring it down to under 8MB